# tkinter crop multiple images OSError: [Errno 22]

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library, crop

I create a script to crop images and save them in multiple equal parts. I'm trying to call it using tkinter but I got always this error. It seems the erro is telling me the name of path is to big but how can I solve this issue.

Any suggestions?

```
def crop():
    global file, basename, chopsize, infile, path
    infile = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:\\2022\\Python program\\Bloc1\\Input bloc1",
                                         title= "Select a File", filetypes=(("jpg files", ".jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
    
    chopsize = 400
    path = Path(infile)
    print(path.name)
    #basename = os.path.basename(infile)
    
    img0 = Image.open(infile)
    #img0 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img0)
    #img0 = Image.open(infile)
    #img0 = Tk.PhotoImage(Image.open(infile))
    #img0 = Image.open(infile, "r")
    #img0 = PIL.Image.open(infile)
    #img0 = cv2.imread(basename)

    #img = ImageOps.grayscale(img)

    width, height = img0.size
    
    print(img0.size)


    # Save Chops of original image
    for x0 in range(0, width, chopsize):
       for y0 in range(0, height, chopsize):
          box = (x0, y0,
                 x0+chopsize if x0+chopsize <  width else  width - 1,
                 y0+chopsize if y0+chopsize < height else height - 1)
          print('%s %s' % (infile, box))
          #img.crop(box).save('zchop.%s.x%03d.y%03d.jpg' % (infile.replace('.jpg',''), x0, y0))
          
          img0.crop(box).save("C:/2022/Python program/Bloc1/Prediction bloc1/Test images/zchop.%s.x%03d.y%03d.jpg" % (infile.replace('.jpg',''), x0, y0))
          #img.crop(box).save("C:/2022/Python program/Bloc1/Prediction bloc1/Test images/zchop.%s.x%03d.y%03d.jpg" % (infile.replace('.jpg',''), x0, y0))
```

```
File "C:\Users\jra02028\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2317, in save
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:/2022/Python program/Bloc1/Prediction bloc1/Test images/zchop.C:/2022/Python program/Bloc1/Input bloc1/predicted_imageCAO2.x000.y000.jpg'
```

Comment: I chose this file from infile (filedialog.askopenfilename) and apperently it takes all the path name... is that correct?

Comment: Why is there `C:` (not the one at the beginning) inside the filename?

Comment: I'm selecting the file from windows by clicking

Comment: this is the problem 'C:/2022/Python program/Bloc1/Prediction bloc1/Test images/zchop.C:/2022/Python program/Bloc1/Input bloc1/predicted_imageCAO2.x000.y000.jpg'

Comment: `infile` is a full pathname, so why do you use it in `img0.crop(box).save("...%s..." % (infile...., x0, y0))`? It puts the full pathname inside another full pathname.

Comment: ok but how can I only use the name predicted_imageCAO2.jpg if I use the Select file window from tkinter?

Comment: Oh I got it!!... name = path.name ... then
img0.crop(box).save("C:/2022/Python program/Bloc1/Prediction bloc1/Test images/zchop.%s.x%03d.y%03d.jpg" % (name.replace('.jpg',''), x0, y0))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `infile` is already a full pathname, the following code will put this full pathname inside another full pathname:

```
"C:/2022/Python program/Bloc1/Prediction bloc1/Test images/zchop.%s.x%03d.y%03d.jpg" % (infile.replace('.jpg',''), x0, y0)
```

which produces an invalid full pathname.

To construct the required full pathname, it is easier to use `pathlib` module:

```
from pathlib import Path
...
# convert infile to Path object
infile = Path(infile)
# output folder
outdir = Path("C:/2022/Python program/Bloc1/Prediction bloc1/Test images")
# construct the output filename
outname = "zchop.%s.x%03d.y%03d%s" % (infile.stem, x0, y0, infile.suffix)
# suggest to use f-string
#outname = f"zchop.{infile.stem}.x{x0:03}.y{y0:03}{infile.suffix}"
# construct the output full pathname
outfile = outdir / outname
```

Then `outfile` is like

```
C:\2022\Python program\Bloc1\Prediction bloc1\Test images\zchop.predicted_imageCAO2.x000.y000.jpg
```